# Can this polynomial have two distinct roots in $[-1,1]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

how can I prove that $f_m(x) = x^3 + 3x +m$ can not have two distinct roots in $[-1,1]$?

I tried Rolle's theorem but this hasn't worked for me. Help, please.

Comment: Who is Joel????

Comment: what have you tried? Note $f_m(x)$ is strictly increasing for all $x$, so what does that tell you about the number of solutions to

$f_m(x) = c$

for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Let us wait until Joel (??) addresses this question ...

Comment: Sorry i was wrong in the interval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has to be a local max or min between two roots, but the derivative of the function is $3(x^2+1)$ which has no real roots. So, there is exactly one real root.

Comment: I was wrong in the interval please some help

Comment: @Knight The interval is irrelevant - Igor's argument shows that the polynomial has only one real zero for any value of $m$.